# How to work with onSaveInstanceState android orientation change

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am working using webservice on android. I was following one of the 
tutorials on lynda.com. I did went through the tuorial. I get data
from webservice and display it in a "ListView". I have MainActivity class
and MyService class which extends the IntentServcie, and POJO class name Course which implement parcelable. It holds part of webservice response I get 
on click.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//member variables I have
    ListView listview;
    List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Course[] courses;
......
    public void runClickHandler(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        //the url where I extract the JSON data
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(JSON_URL));
        startService(intent);

    }
```

In MyService class download the response from the webservice and 
I open a connection

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", TOKEN);
```

I use GSON library to convert JSON , package the data and send it to MainActivity using LocalBroadcastManager.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          ...........
          messageIntent.putExtra(MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD, courseList);
        //we package the data we want to share to the rest of the applicaiton
        LocalBroadcastManager manager =   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        manager.sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
        }
```

On my MainActivity i use BroadcastReceiver to get data and display it on listview. Inside OnReceive method of BroadcastReceiver. I have this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            courses = (Course[]) intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MyService.MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD);

            for (Course course : courses) {

                courseList.add(course.getCourseTitle());
            }
            Collections.sort(courseList);

           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                    courseList);

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

The problem comes when I change screen orientation. The data I got from webservice gets destroyed. I read recommendation to set things on XML file to adjust screen size changes, which also considered not a "good approach". What I thought using is override onSaveInstanceState as suggested by other posts here or online. I do struggle to connect the pieces, and retain my data during orientation change.
    How should I handle things? I would appreciate any good article you read, or how you approach the problem based on my implementation above. How do I handle the display onCreate after checking if(savedInstanceState != null)? Which member variables data should I save? Does everything change to null onDestroy()? This is onCreate() method I have

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
   .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter(MyService.MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE));

            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
    out.putParcelableArrayList("COURSES", courseList);
}
```

2.

```
onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    // ...
    if (savedState != null) {
         courseList = savedState.getParcelableArrayList("COURSES");
    }
}
```

P.S. 
* https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html 
* https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras

Comment: If I add what you suggested on onSaveInstanceState, I get error Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>', required: 'java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>

Comment: ok, I updated your feedback to use out.putParcelableArray("COURSES", courses); and onCreate() I got the courses courses = (Course[])savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("COURSES"); I still have the main issue displaying the courses. Initially the courses were displayed with onClick trigger, now with screen rotation I want them displayed

Answer (score 0):

Even before I post the question, I have looked tutorials and stackoverflow responses. It took me long to digest. MaxV pointed me to the right direction. On savedInstanceState I added this

```
//I have coures parcelable array object as a member variable
// Course[] courses;
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArray("COURSES", courses);

    }
```

OnCreate() method I am getting array of courses, and I created another helper method to display the coures list

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            courses = (Course[])savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("COURSES");
            displayListOfCourses(courses);
        }
```

I created displayListOfCourses, I took part of the code from BroadcastReciever I had earlier, and made it reusable. My initial assumption was by having list of courses somehow the list will show up. Now, my understanding is that I have to create the view objects, ListView, and arrayAdapter and rebuild the view myself.

```
public void displayListOfCourses(Course[] courses){
        for (Course course : courses) {

            courseList.add(course.getCourseTitle());
        }
        Collections.sort(courseList);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                courseList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```